# JDK and security for a Windows machine

Tags: android

I'm hoping to learn to develop Android apps, but for the tutorial I'm learning I need Android Studio. Is installing the JDK a bad move from a security stance on a Windows 8 machine?

Edit-

The combination of Windows and Java software seems to be discouraged because of security issues. How true/accurate is this? Is the JDK the same as the Java that needs to be installed for some websites?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking if the JDK is secure? If the combo of the JDK and Windows 8 is secure? Then the question is, "secure for what?" Are you assuming that the JDK includes malware? Please flesh out your question.

Comment: People are not gonna start "hacking you" because you install the Android JDK. The whole discussion of the security shortcomings of Java compared to other languages for OS security is completely, completely different, and most of what you'll find on people's blogs will be outdated because the JVM has changed a lot, and so have the security challenges of OS security in the past 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

JDK contains Java plugin for browsers, so if you didn't have any previous JDK/JRE on your computer, you expose yourself to attack using malicious Java code from website.

Of course you can manuall disable Java plugin, but you have to do it separately for every browser and user.

If you have some previous JDK/JRE version, then most probably you will just upgrade your existing Java browser plugin, which is good from security perspective.